# Does asmlinkage mean stack or registers?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, x86, function-attributes

In most languages, C included, the stack is used for function calls. That's why you get a "Stack Overflow" error if you are not careful in recursion. (Pun not intended).

If that is true, then what is so special about the `asmlinkage` GCC directive.

It says, from [#kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/asmlinkage)

> The asmlinkage tag is one other thing that we should observe about
> this simple function. This is a #define for some gcc magic that tells
> the compiler that the function should not expect to find any of its
> arguments in registers (a common optimization), but only on the CPU's
> stack.

I mean I don't think the **registers are used in normal function calls**.

What is even more strange is when you learn it is [implemented using the GCC `regparm` function attribute on x86](https://qr.ae/pNy1wL).

The documentation of [`regparm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes) is as follows:

> On x86-32 targets, the regparm attribute causes the compiler to pass
> arguments number one to number if they are of integral type in
> registers EAX, EDX, and ECX instead of on the stack.

This is basically saying the opposite of what `asmlinkage` is trying do.

So what happens? Are they on the stack or in the registers.

Where am I going wrong?

The information isn't very clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On x86 32bit, the `asmlinkage` macro [expands to](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7-rc4/source/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h#L11) `__attribute__((regparam(0)))`, which basically tells GCC that *no parameters* should be passed through registers (the `0` is the important part). As of Linux 5.17, x86-32 and Itanium64 seem to be the only two architectures re-defining this macro, which by default [expands to no attribute](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/include/linux/linkage.h#L22) at all.

So `asmlinkage` does not by itself mean "parameters are passed on the stack". By default, the normal calling convention is used. This includes x86 64bit, which follows the System V AMD64 ABI calling convention, passing function parameters through RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9, [XYZ]MM0–7.

**HOWEVER** there is an important clarification to make: even with no special `__attribute__` to force the compiler to use the stack for parameters, syscalls in recent kernel versions still take parameters from the stack *indirectly* through a pointer to a `pt_regs` structure (holding all the user-space registers saved on the stack on syscall entry). This is achieved through a moderately complex set of macros (`SYSCALL_DEFINEx`) that does everything transparently.

So *technically*, although `asmlinkage` does not change the calling convention, parameters are **not** passed inside registers as one would think by simply looking at the syscall function signature.

For example, the following syscall:

```c
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(something, int, one, int, two, int, three)
{
    // ...
    do_something(one, two, three);
    // ...
}
```

Actually becomes (roughly):

```c
asmlinkage __x64_sys_something(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    // ...
    do_something(regs->di, regs->si, regs->dx);
    // ...
}
```

Which compiles to something like:

```
/* ... */
mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdi+0x60]
mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rdi+0x68]
mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rdi+0x70]
call   do_something
/* ... */
```

Comment: So what you are saying is basically that in normal cases functions can be on the stack or in the registers. `asmlinkage` just guarantees they will **ALWAYS** be on the stack. Am I correct ?

Comment: "On x86 64bit, it expands to the more specific __attribute__((syscall_linkage)) instead." I could be wrong, but the link seems to be for the IA-64 (Itanium) architecture, not x86-64.

Comment: @LéoLam you're not wrong, indeed that's Itanium 64, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2):

On i386 and x86-64 at least, **`asmlinkage` means to use the standard calling convention you'd get with no GCC options and no `__attribute__`**.  (Like what user-space programs normally use for that target.)

**For i386, that means stack args only.  For x86-64, it's still the same registers as usual.**

---

For x86-64, there's no difference; the kernel already uses the standard calling convention from the AMD64 System V ABI doc everywhere, because it's well-designed for efficiency, passing the first 6 integer args in registers.

But i386 has more historical baggage, with the standard calling convention (i386 SysV ABI) inefficiently passing all args on the stack.  Presumably at some point in ancient history, Linux was compiled by GCC using this convention, and the hand-written asm entry points that called C functions were already using that convention.

So (I'm guessing here), when Linux wanted to switch from `gcc -m32` to `gcc -m32 -mregparm=3` to build the kernel with a more efficient calling convention, they had a choice to either modify the hand-written asm at the same time to use the new convention, or to force a few specific C functions to still use the traditional calling convention so the hand-written asm could stay the same.

If they'd made the former choice, `asmlinkage` for i386 would be `__attribute__((regparm(3)))` to force that convention even if the kernel is compiled a different way.

But instead, they chose to keep the asm the same, and `#define asmlinkage __attribute__((regparm(0)))` for i386, which indeed is zero register args, using the stack right away.

I don't know if that maybe had any debugging benefit, like in terms of being able to see what args got passed into a C function from asm without the only copy likely getting modified right away.

If `-mregparm=3` and the corresponding attribute were new GCC features, Linus probably wanted to keep it possible to build the kernel with older GCC.  That would rule out changing the asm to require `__attribute__((regparm(3)))`.  The asmlinkage = regparm(0) choice they actually made also has the advantage of not having to modify any asm, which means no correctness concerns, and that can be disentangled from any possible GCC bugs with using the new(?)-at-the-time calling convention.

At this point I think it would be totally possible to modify the asm code that calls `asmlinkage` functions, and swap it to being regparm(3).  But that's a pretty minor thing.  And not worth doing now since 32-bit x86 kernels are long since obsolete for almost all use cases.  You almost always want a 64-bit kernel even if using a 32-bit user-space.

There might even be an efficiency benefit to stack args if saving the registers at a system-call entry point involved saving them with EBX at the lowest address, where they're already in place to be used as function args.  You'd be all set to `call *ia32_sys_call_table(,%eax,4)`.  But that isn't actually safe because callees own their stack args and are allowed to write them, even though GCC usually doesn't use the incoming stack arg locations as scratch space.  So I doubt Linux would have done this.

---

Other ISAs cope just fine with asmlinkage passing args in registers, so there's nothing fundamental about stack args that's important for how Linux works.  (Except possibly for i386-specific code, but I doubt even that.)

**The whole "asmlinkage means to pass args on the stack" is purely an i386 thing.**

Most other ISAs that Linux runs on are more recent than 32-bit x86 (and/or are RISC-like with more registers), and have a standard calling convention that's more efficient with modern CPUs, using registers for the first few args.  That includes x86-64.