# How are parameters passed to Linux system call ? Via register or stack?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, calling-convention

I trying to understand the internals of the Linux kernel by reading [Robert Love's Linux Kernel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003V4ATI0).

On page 74 he says the easiest way to pass arguments to a `syscall` is via :

> Somehow, user-space must relay the parameters to the kernel during the
>   trap.The easiest way to do this is via the same means that the syscall
>   number is passed: The parameters are stored in registers. On x86-32,
>   the registers ebx, ecx, edx, esi, and edi contain, in order, the first
>   five arguments.

Now this is bothering me for a number of reasons:

1. All syscalls are defined with the `asmlinkage` option. Which implies that the arguments are [always to be found on the stack and not the register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61636442/7134737). So what is all this business with the registers ?
2. It may be possible that before the syscall is performed the values are copied on to the kernel stack. I have no idea why that would be efficient but it might be a possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(This answer is for 32-bit x86 Linux to match your question; things are slightly different for 64-bit x86 and other architectures.)

The parameters are passed from userspace in registers as Love says.

When userspace invokes a system call with `int $0x80`, the kernel syscall entry code gets control.  This is written in assembly language and can be seen [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d5eeab8d7e269e8cfc53b915bccd7bd30485bcbf/arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S#L1072), for instance.  One of the things this code does is to take the parameters from the registers and push them onto the stack, and then call the appropriate kernel `sys_XXX()` function (which is written in C).  So those functions do indeed expect their arguments on the stack.

It wouldn't work as well to try to pass parameters from userspace to the kernel on the stack.  When the system call is made, the CPU switches to a separate kernel stack, so the parameters would have to be copied from the userspace stack to the kernel stack, and this is somewhat complicated.  And it would have to be done even for very simple system calls that just take a few numeric arguments and wouldn't otherwise need to access userspace memory at all (think about `close()` for instance).

Comment: What is the advantage of copying them again on the kernel stack ? Why not just use them from the registers, its faster anyways.

Comment: Well, passing arguments on the stack has always been the default convention for C functions on x86-32; the `asmlinkage` just ensures that the compiler does not try to deviate from that.  In principle the `sys_XXX()` functions could be declared with an alternate convention (e.g. `fastcall`) where parameters are passed in registers; however, this convention doesn't have parameters in the same registers in the same order as the int $0x80 API prescribes, so some shuffling of registers would be needed.

Comment: And pushing registers onto the kernel stack is pretty cheap - I don't think there would be much difference in overhead between that and the necessary register-shuffling for `fastcall`.  So since the code originally would have assumed stack-passing (`fastcall` was a later innovation), I don't think there would have ever been a good reason to rewrite it.